# possibility of unique value for constants

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

If the equation $$(p+2q)x+(2p+5q)y=4a+3b $$ represents the equation of the line $$2x+3y=13$$ can the value of $p$ and $q$ be uniquely determined? No information about $a$ and $b$ has been provided. I feel that it cannot be uniquely determined as the equation of the line can also be written with all coefficients multiplied by some number which will give different values of $p$ and $q$. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Maybe $p=f(a,b)$ and $q=g(a,b)$ for some functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can there be any modification to this question such that p and q can be uniquely determined?

Comment: Tack some condition onto $p$ and $q$, e.g., insist $p+q=7$, that will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine $p$ and $q$ if you know $4a+3b$. But in the absence of such information, there are multiple solutions: one can multiply $p$, $q$, and $4a+3b$ by the same constant.

With some normalizing condition, such as $p+q=1$, the solution would be  unique.

(Compilation of comments by [Gerry Myerson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546807/possibility-of-unique-value-for-constants#comment1165948_546807))